# Drive stepper motor with potentiometer in Siemens PLC

Tags: stepper-motor, potentiometer, plc, siemens

It is difficult for me to drive a stepper motor with potentiometer (position stepper motor with position potentiometer).

I've done program, to see the value from potentiometer with NORM_X.

I am using CPU 1214C DC/DC/DC with program TIA V14.

How can I match the potentiometer value with the stepper motor position?
Would it be better with PID 3step? But, how?

Answer (score 0):

You control the stepper motor with technology object TO_Axis. Then you have to configure units, lead screw pitch, gearbox transfer ratio, ...etc. You do use then the PLCopen commands, for example MC_MoveAbsolute or MC_MoveRelative.

As for your application you should home your axis to a reference position using active homing procedure by means of using a reference sensor. The axis shall move and search for reference sensor during MC_Home, once it finds its home position, you could use MC_MoveAbsolute and give the position setpoint as potentiometer reading to move the axis.